# Convergence of a sequence of functions in $L^2(\Bbb R)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am mainly thrown off by the notation of the following problems,  where **0** is the zero signal.

**Problem 1:**
Find a sequence $x_1, x_2,...$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k =$ **0** but $\lim x_k(t) \neq $ **0** for infinitely many $t \in \Bbb R$.

**Attempt at problem 1:** So I understand that $x_1, x_2, ...$ is a series of functions in $t$.  I gave my answer as $\frac{1}{k} \sin(t)$ since as $k \rightarrow \infty, x_k \rightarrow 0$ but there are still infinitely many values for $t$ in which the function does not equal zero.  Is this the right state of mind?

---

**Problem 2**
Find a sequence $y_1, y_2, ...$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} = 0$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$ but $\lim y_k \neq$ **0**

**Attempt at problem 2:**  So when it says $\lim y_k \neq$ **0**, does this mean for any given $k$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, the limit does not converge to 0 or as $k$ AND $t$ approach infinity? I put $\frac{1}{k}e^{-t}$ as my answer, but I don't have much to back it up other than that when I found the limit as both approached infinity in WolframAlpha, no limit existed.

---

**Problem 3**

Find sequence $z_1, z_2, ...$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} z_k =$ **0** but $z_k(t)$ does not converge to zero for any $t \in [0,1]$.

**Attempt at problem 3:** This one is throwing me off.  I'm guessing there is something where the denominator equals zero so that the function value shoots up but am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Note that both $\frac{1}{k}\sin t$ and $\frac{1}{k} e^{-t}$ are not in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: So this actually brings up a good question for me.  I'm fairly new to this material and am still getting around some of the basic concepts.  For a function to be in $L^2$, the square root of the integral of the absolute square of the function must be finite, correct? How can this be seen quickly and intuitively.  On first glance of $\frac{1}{k} \sin t$, I feel like it would fulfill that condition since $\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges to zero.

Comment: But you are fixing $k$ fixed right? $\sin$ is periodic, so if it is  not identically zero, the integral has to be infinite.

Comment: Oh I see.  So, for example, would $\frac{1}{kt}$ be in $L^2$? Furthermore would this fulfill the requirements for Problem 1?

Comment: This is also not in $L^2$. Do you know why?

Comment: I guess just because $\frac{1}{t^2}$ converges to zero, it doesn't mean the integral is finite, and more specifically that the integral of $1/t^2$ is infinite.

Comment: You are correct. Indeed, most "common" function such as polynomials, tri functions are not in $L^2$. So you might try to define your function by hand... For example, consider $f(x) = 1$ if $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. This function is in $L^2$.

Comment: Ok so now I can see how a sequence of functions in $L^2$ can converge to 0 as $k \rightarrow \infty$. For example, $x_k = a/k$ for $t \in (b1, b2)$ where $a, b1, \text{and} b2$ are all constants.  The integral of the square in this case is finite.  However, I'm then still hung up on the idea that $\lim x_k \neq 0$ for infinitely many $t \in \Bbb R$.  Is this saying the limit as $t$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Oh I am just giving an example of an $L^2$ function. In your case, you really have $lim x_k =0$ for all $t$.

Comment: You may consider for example $x_n(t) = t^n$ when $t\in [0,1]$

Comment: The function $\frac{sin(t)}{kt}$ is in $L^2$ yes?  Furthermore, as $k \rightarrow \infty, x_k \rightarrow 0$.  There are also infinitely many values of $t$ were $x_k$ is not zero.  However, I'm guessing this does not fulfill the condition that $\lim$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ should not converge to 0?

Comment: The function is in $L^2$. However, $lim\ x_k=0$ everywhere.

Comment: So to clarify, $\lim x_k$ is asking for the limit of the function as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I think the limit is on $k$. May I can write down a solution to your problem so that you might get a better picture.

Comment: That would be helpful.  At first I thought it was as $k \rightarrow \infty$, but then the second problem seems like it is contradicting itself, although I'm guessing it has something to do with the idea that **0** $\neq 0$?

Comment: $0$ is referring both to the number $0$ and the zero function in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: Consider the function $f_k(t) = t^k$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. Then consider

$$x_k(t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}f_k(x - 2i)  \ .$$

Then as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_k^2 (t) dt = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} \frac{1}{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2k+1} \to 0$$

as $k \to \infty$, then $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k = 0$. (This means that the sequence of funcions $x_k$ converges to $0$ in the $L^2$ norm. However, at $t = 1, 3, 5,....$ we have

$$x_k(1) = 1, x_k(3) = \frac{1}{2},\ x_k(2n+1) = \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Thus $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k(t)\neq 0$ for $t= 1, 3, 5, ...$

Problem 2: Let $y_k$ be the function defined by (Just translating the interval to the right)

$$y_k(x) = 1\ \ \text{if }x\in [k, k+1]\ \text{and }=0 \ \text{otherwise.}$$

Then for all $t\in \mathbb R$, $lim_{k\to \infty} y_k(t)=0$. But $y_k$ as a whole does not converges to the zero function in $L^2$, because

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2_k(t) dt = 1,\ \ \forall k$$

Problem 3: This one is a little more tricky. I just briefly discribe the construction. Let $y_1$ be the function that is one in $[0, 1/2]$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $y_2$ be the function which is one in $[1/2, 1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

For $y_3, y_4, y_5$, we chop $[0,1]$ into 3 equal portion and let $y_3, y_4, y_5$ to be one in each portions. Then we chop $[0,1]$ into 4 portion and define $y_6$ to $y_9$ and so on.

This sequence $y_k$ will converges to $0$ in $L^2$. However, for each $t\in [0,1]$, $y_k(t)$ is not convergent (because it is sometimes $0$ and sometimes $1$, depending on $k$.